# Is there any Post method base in CodeIgniter pagination?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter's pagination API. I found some issues when I click on particular page: it shows controller and pages in URL. I dont want to show all the details in URL.

I have large number of search criteria.

e.g.
http://localhost/myapp/search/pages/2&fromAge=25...... so on

Is there any way to handle it using POST method rather than GET?

Please help.

Comment: Pagination using POST doesn't make sense. Why can't you expose at least the page number?

Comment: What BoltClock said. Plus, hiding search parameters will create usability issues. Say one of your visitors wants to send his buddy the link to second page of search result for the query term "xyz". If he sends /controller/search that doesn't make a lot of sense, doesn't it? /controller/search?q=xyz&p=2 is much better.

Comment: @kitsched: sending a link to a page in a paginated set makes no sense either, since its contents will likely change. Either way, still agree that including the parameters is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the pagination with POST, there is a simple way to do that with the standard CI pagination and without Ajax. You can perform a POST instead of the GET 
when one click on the pagination links. 
For this you need an hidden field in the form (named page in my example) which contains the page number and you need to set the action attribute of the form with the link before submitting it (it is necessary for the pagination class to compute the current page). Find below a sample code in jquery :

```
// bind onclick event to the pagination links
$('.pagination a').click(function () {
    var link = $(this).get(0).href; // get the link from the DOM object
    var form = $('#form1'); // get the form you want to submit
    var segments = link.split('/');
    // assume the page number is the fifth parameter of the link
    $('#page').val(segments[4]); // set a hidden field with the page number
    form.attr('action', link); // set the action attribute of the form
    form.submit(); // submit the form
    return false; // avoid the default behaviour of the link
});
```

On the server side, you read the page number from the 
POST field named page to perform the db query with pagination and you build the pagination links with the usual function

Answer (score 0):

What about using AJAX?

http://tohin.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/codeigniter-ajax-pagination/

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/AJAX_Pagination_with_CI_Pagination_Library/